# Add new user into Wso2 CEP into H2 database

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I need to add new user in Wso2 CEP (3.1.0) and I know that is possible by "clicking" few steps in console (example from documentation). I wonder if it possible to add new user without login into console, but connect to H2 database and insert user there?

I know that new user is save into "UM_USER" table.
Maybe someone knows what class write user into H2, how passowrd is enrcypted and what is "UM_SALT_VALUE" and why I need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to manage users programmatically, a better way rather than trying to modify H2 DB is to do it through the relevant admin service. This way you don't have to bother about the underlying user-store or the salt values used for hashing passwords etc.

In Carbon-based products, most of the configurations done through the web console can be done programmatically by calling the relevant admin web service, such as user management, adding/managing deployment artifacts etc.

So for you use case, you can use the User Management admin service at:
https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl

Note that in order to access this wsdl, you should make these admin service wsdl's visible by editing `<CEP>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` and restart the server.

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

Comment: Ooo thx you a lot! I found this blog http://charithaka.blogspot.nl/2013/06/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html and try out how to add new user. Everything works fine. I noticed that in SoapUI in "Authorization" I have these options: Basic, NTLM, SPNEGO/Kerberos. Is it possible to authorize it by oAuth2?

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a possible way to authorize something else than "BASIC" in User Admin services?